# Can't seem to match a timestamp to created date range in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am relatively new to coding and trying to merge a datetime column with a created daterange in Pandas.

I am trying to match datetime column `StartDate` (from DataFrame `energy`), that has been put into variable `start_dates`, with a created DatetimeIndex called `timeline` so that I have a time series.

This looks as such:

```
In [1]: start_dates
Out[1]:
0        2016-06-25 00:00:00
1        2016-06-26 00:00:00
2        2016-06-27 00:00:00
```

`rates` is a DataFrame with a series of rates that I am trying to include in to give information of the rates for a particular time by appending to `start_dates`:

```
In [2]: rates
Out[2]:
   Rate1
0  4.8
1  5.9
2  2.6
```

I have tried to match the timestamp in `start_dates` to the date range in `timeline`.

I have tried every which way there is, including join, merge, insert, concat, append, and assign, but I can't get the two to merge.

My latest attempt is:

```
timeline = pd.date_range('2007-03', '2022-06') #231 months
timeline = timeline.to_frame([timeline])

start_dates = energy.loc[:, 'StartDate']
start_dates = datetime.datetime.strptime(first_thous[:, 'StartDate'], '%Y-%m-%d').date()

rates = energy.loc[:, 'Rate1']
start_dates.append(rates)

timeline = timeline.reset_index(drop = True)
timeline.join(start_dates, how = 'inner')
print(timeline)
```

But although there is no error, the columns do not seem to either append or join any of the columns together, so I can't actually tell why it isn't working.

What is going on here?

The expected result would be:

```
In [3]: timeline
Out[3]:
             Rate1
0 2016-06-25 4.8
1 2016-06-26 5.9
2 2016-06-27 2.6
```

Comment: It might help people trying to answer to tell that this is using pandas

Comment: @Bushman thanks, always forget that.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output? I think [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)  should help

Comment: @jezrael thanks!. Have attempted to provide sample data with expected output too. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
energy = pd.DataFrame({'Rate1':[4.8,5.9,2.6],
                       'StartDate':['2007-02-28 00:00:00',
                                    '2007-03-01 00:00:00',
                                    '2007-03-02 00:00:00']})
print (energy)
   Rate1            StartDate
0    4.8  2007-02-28 00:00:00
1    5.9  2007-03-01 00:00:00
2    2.6  2007-03-02 00:00:00


timeline = pd.date_range('2007-03', '2022-06')
print (timeline)
DatetimeIndex(['2007-03-01', '2007-03-02', '2007-03-03', '2007-03-04',
               '2007-03-05', '2007-03-06', '2007-03-07', '2007-03-08',
               '2007-03-09', '2007-03-10',
               ...
               '2022-05-23', '2022-05-24', '2022-05-25', '2022-05-26',
               '2022-05-27', '2022-05-28', '2022-05-29', '2022-05-30',
               '2022-05-31', '2022-06-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=5572, freq='D')
```

Don’t select columns to separate Series or DataFrames. Simply convert column `StartDate` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then filter by *[Boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)* with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
energy['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(energy['StartDate'])
df = energy[energy['StartDate'].isin(timeline)]
print (df)
   Rate1  StartDate
1    5.9 2007-03-01
2    2.6 2007-03-02
```

Another solution:

```
energy['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(energy['StartDate'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'StartDate':timeline}).merge(energy)
print (df)
   StartDate  Rate1
0 2007-03-01    5.9
1 2007-03-02    2.6
```

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear enough but the only problem is that DataFrame `energy` has Start Dates which relates `Rate1` to a specific index which would be lost if just creating my own timeline.

Comment: In short, energy has a number of time intervals which I am trying to create in a time series instead. Of which this question was just the initial step to create start date. Apologies if this doesn't make much sense, I have only been doing it a month and am struggling to explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: thanks, looks like it could work. Only problem left is that `Rate` and `StartDate` in energy have over a million rows therefore I needed something to create new DataFrame from those two. When tried, I couldn't seem to add multiple columns from `energy` to a new variable.

Comment: @geds133 - Hard to know if million of rows. Added new solution, but maybe here is better use some db like sqlite and merge there for better performance.

Comment: I think you may be right, as `energy` also has 108 other columns with different data in. I will assess other options. Thanks for the time you made trying to solve my issue.